# How to get product id using order items id in woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, product, orders, coupon

I have Created a coupon programmatically using this documentation -> https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/create-a-coupon-programatically/

It's work good and generate one dynamic coupon code after complete the order. But i want to allow that coupon code only for that ordered product.

So on above code here:

update_post_meta( $new_coupon_id, 'product_ids', '' );

i want to get that order product ID using that order item id.

So any one know solutions for this then please help me.

Thanks,
Ketan.

Comment: Is this coupon for one product or multiple?

Comment: See [this link](http://www.webhat.in/article/woocommerce-tutorial/how-to-get-order-details-by-order-id/) you can use `$order->get_items()` to loop it and create an array of product ID.

Comment: @Sajjadur Rahman Sagor,

Only for that order products only. not for multiple products. For more information please review this screen shot -> http://nimb.ws/ly9NaZ

Thanks.

Comment: @Raunak Gupta,

Can you please review this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46707433/how-to-generate-woocommerce-coupon-code-dynamically-using-programming-code/46707664#46707664  and provide me solutions for my above requirements.

thanks.

Comment: @KetanPatel:if there are n number of product an order then you want to generate n number of coupon?

Comment: @Raunak Gupta,

Yes that code works good. Now only remaining that each product coupon code only apply for that product only. So if you know solutions then inform me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**You can get product_id by using $order->get_items() function in WooCommerce**

```
$order = new WC_Order( $order_id );
    $items = $order->get_items();
    foreach ( $items as $item ) {
        $item_id = $item['order_item_id']; 
        $product_name = $item['name'];
        $product_id = $item['product_id'];
    }
```